# programmatically finding out AWS KMS last key useage date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I am in the process of gathering all KMS Key Usage Date from AWS KMS cloud trail logs.

Is there a way of retrieving the last key usage date programmatically and export it to Json or CSV via AWS API Calls? Some KMS events do not return any resource name until you go into the actual log making this a bit tricky.

I used lookupevents but some KMS actions such as decrypt do not have any resource name in the attributes of the Cloud trail logs.